# Ensure that an object is always member of a List?

Tags: java, list, design-patterns

Imagine the following:

Every word is a list of characters. However there can be no character itself, it always has to be part of a word.

So the Word class could look like this:

```
class Word extends List<MyCharacter>
```

Now, how could one enforce that it isn't possible to instantiate a `MyCharacter` which is not part of a `Word`? Maybe make `MyCharacter` an private inner class of `Word` and add a method like `addCharacter(String character)` to `Word`? But then, would it be possible to let `Word` extend the List class while `MyCharacter` is a private inner class of `Word`?

Thanks for any hint on this!

Update:

I now ended up at

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public final class Word extends ArrayList<Word.MyCharacter> {

    protected final class MyCharacter
    {
        private String character;

        public String getCharacter() {
            return character;
        }

        public MyCharacter(String character)
        {
            this.character=character;
        }
    }

    public void addCharacter(String character) {
        add(new MyCharacter(character));
    }   
}
```

And here is how it's used:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Word word = new Word();

    // word.add(new MyCharacter("a")); // as intended: not possible, because MyCharacter class can't be accessed
    word.addCharacter("a"); // ok           
}
```

Comment: With `Character`, do you mean `java.lang.Character`, or is it one of your own classes? It's not a good idea to create your own classes with the same name as existing standard classes.

Comment: No object is ever in any other object. There are only references. And all references, be they from the guts of `List<>` or from a a method of `Word` or from somewhere else entirely, are equal before the law. Your query just doesn't even make sense from the language's perspective, and you'll be hard pressed to implement it literally. Perhaps rephrase it so it reflects your actual goal?

Comment: Thanks for the hint, it's one of my own classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible, in theory. One problem will arise in that `Character` is already a java class. Also, if you're using Eclipse, it won't let you declare

```
public class Word extends ArrayList<Letter> {
    private class Letter {
        //...
    }
}
```

unless you make Letter at most protected. I'm not sure whether that's an Eclipse issue or if Java would also stop you.

Regarding your superclass problem, it's because you cannot use List as it is only an interface. You must use something that implements it, like ArrayList.

Comment: Thank you for the hints, I now got a working example, see above :-)

Comment: "One problem will arise in that Character is already a java class." - This shouldn't be a problem in any way. It's perfectly ok to have multiple classes of the same name, including the names of those classes provided by the Java API.

Answer (score 1):

> Maybe make Character an private inner class of Word and add a method like addCharacter(String character) to Word?

Yes. - Or maybe only declare the constructor of `MyCharacter` private and the `MyCharacter` class `final`. Or declare the `MyCharacter` class outside of `Word` having a 'package-private' constructor. Or have a kind of (static) factory method inside `MyCharacter` like `appendToWord( Word w, Character char )` and a private constructor. Or ... :-)

Edit: I first misunderstood the question:

> would it be possible to let Word extend the List class with the private inner Character class?

`Word` can extend `List<T>` in any way. But -as you figured out- not `List<Word.SomeInnerClass>`.

Comment: Hanno, I can't completely follow your reply, could you modify my posted example? Thanks :-)

Comment: If I declare a constructor private, how can I instantiate such a class at all?

Comment: 'It just works' ;) - See for example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/663059/why-do-inner-classes-make-private-methods-accessible

Comment: Thanks for updating my question and your reply Hanno, my question wasn't clear at the beginning, my fault. Also thanks for the hints, though I find the idea of @CapnSmack more comfortable.

Comment: Hanno, interesting link, so makign the inner class public and the constructor private also works the same, I just tested this. Damn, I can't accept two replies ): Could you add your comment to your reply? Upvoted your reply :-)