# PMD rule Accessor Method Generation

Tags: pmd

Can anyone explain bit in detail about this rule. Rule:AccessorMethodGeneration Priority:3 Avoid autogenerated methods to access private fields and methods of inner / outer classes with concrete examples for both fields and methods?

Answer (score 2):

The [PMD documentation provides a summary](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/snapshot/pmd_rules_java_bestpractices.html#accessormethodgeneration) of the **AccessorMethodGeneration** rule, with my emphasis added:

> When accessing a private field / method from another class, **the Java
>   compiler will generate a accessor methods with package-private
>   visibility. This adds overhead**, and to the dex method count on
>   Android. This situation can be avoided by changing the visibility of
>   the field / method from private to package-private.

So PMD is advising you that if you make such members and methods package-private instead of private you will avoid the overhead of having to access them through compiler generated accessor methods. (I'm not an Android developer so I can't comment on the "dex method count" issue.)

This is the code example PMD provides with respect to private members:

```
public class OuterClass {
    private int counter;
    /* package */ int id;

    public class InnerClass {
        InnerClass() {
            OuterClass.this.counter++; // wrong accessor method will be generated
        }

        public int getOuterClassId() {
            return OuterClass.this.id; // id is package-private, no accessor method needed
        }
    }
}
```

And [here is an SO example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/663059/why-do-inner-classes-make-private-methods-accessible/663147#663147) where the compiler will auto-generate code to access private methods. Note the poster's comment (with my emphasis added):

> The compiler takes the inner classes and turns them into top-level
>   classes. **Since private methods are only available to the inner class
>   the compiler has to add new "synthetic" methods that have package
>   level access** so that the top-level classes have access to it.

In summary, PMD is flagging code where you can make performance improvements (which I would think would usually be very minor) in some scenarios by modifying the access on private members and private methods.

One other point worth noting is that there are some PMD bug reports on **AccessorMethodGeneration** not working properly (e.g. https://github.com/pmd/pmd/issues/274 and https://github.com/pmd/pmd/issues/342). So if you can't understand why PMD is flagging your code with a **AccessorMethodGeneration** warning, check the bug reports.

Comment: As for the Android issue, Android's Dalvik VM packages classes in a custom .dex format. Dex files are restricted to 64k fields and 64k methods. If more are needed, the application is split into 2 or more dex files. This split impacts heavily on application startup time, so it's good to avoid it when possible (proguard helps a lot!). Getting away of that limit by getting rid of the synthetic methods is of high importance, even more than the performance benefit of removing the overhead (hence it being a bestpractice rule and not a performance rule).

Comment: As per the comments for static inner class : https://github.com/pmd/pmd/issues/274. This defect is fixed in 5.5.x version. However, latest version for maven-pmd-plugin is 3.9.0 on URL https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-pmd-plugin. Thus, I am not sure how to overcome this. Please assist?

Comment: @user3382677 The version 3.9.0 you cite relates to the PMD plugin, not PMD itself. And if you look at the dependencies for the plugin you will see it mentions PMD version 6.x, so if issue #274 was fixed in 5.5.x there will not be a problem. Just add the XML provided for **maven-pmd-plugin** as a dependency in your pom.xml and you should be fine.

Comment: <!-- PMD -->
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
<configuration>
<failOnViolation>true</failOnViolation>
<printFailingErrors>true</printFailingErrors>
<sourceEncoding>utf-8</sourceEncoding>
<linkXRef>false</linkXRef>
<rulesets>
<ruleset>${project.basedir}/PMDRulesets.xml</ruleset>
</rulesets>
</configuration>
<executions>
<execution>
<id>pmd-check</id>
<phase>process-classes</phase>
<goals>
<goal>check</goal>
</goals>
</execution>
</executions>
</plugin>

Comment: I have added the above one. In .m2, I can see the version "maven-pmd-plugin-3.9.0.jar" as expected, but still getting the error from the PMD, I have static inner class.

Comment: static class DefaultThreadGroup extends ThreadGroup{
        DefaultThreadGroup(ThreadGroup parent, String name){
            super(parent, name);
        }
        public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e){
            if(LOGGER.isErrorEnabled()) {
                LOGGER.error("Exception in thread: {} " + t, e);
            }
        }
    }
Error: CustomThreadFactory$DefaultThreadGroup:98 Rule:AccessorMethodGeneration Priority:3 Avoid autogenerated methods to access private fields and methods of inner / outer classes. where CustomThreadFactory is a outerclass

Comment: @user3382677 Please create a new post for this. Pursuing it in comments is inappropriate, and it is not directly related to your original question which asked for an explanation of the **AccessorMethodGeneration** rule with examples.